# PyPI: Problems uploading a module

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I am trying to upload a python module to PyPI using setuptools and twine. My module can be seen at https://pypi.org/project/mousecontroller/. If you try installing the module using `pip install mousecontroller`, you will encounter an error:

```
Collecting mousecontroller
  Using cached mousecontroller-1.0.2.tar.gz (1.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\me\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packa
ges (from mousecontroller) (223)
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\me\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packag
es (from mousecontroller) (0.13.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\me\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-pa
ckages (from pypiwin32->mousecontroller) (304)
Building wheels for collected packages: mousecontroller
  Building wheel for mousecontroller (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_scripts
      creating build
      creating build\scripts-3.9
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'm'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mousecontroller
  Running setup.py clean for mousecontroller
Failed to build mousecontroller
Installing collected packages: mousecontroller
  Running setup.py install for mousecontroller ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for mousecontroller did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34:
SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_scripts
      creating build
      creating build\scripts-3.9
      error: file 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60u406eb\mousecontroller_e9ecf1693b5a49f6aa898bb92d39281a\m' does not exist
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> mousecontroller

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have done some research on this problem and still have not found anything relevant to me or how to fix this. Here is my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mousecontroller',
    version='1.0.2',
    author='(my name)',
    author_email='(my e-mail)',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://pypi.org/project/mousecontroller/',
    license='LICENSE',
    description='A python package to easily control the mouse in realistic and fluent ways.',
    long_description=open('README.md', 'r').read(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    scripts='mousecontroller.py',
    install_requires=['pypiwin32', 'keyboard'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

note: I have edited the code and log to protect some of my personal information.

Comment: `I have edited the code and log to protect some of my personal information.` <- they are publicly available though when someone downloads and extracts the `tar.gz` from pypi.

Comment: Can you provide a breakdown of how your project directory is structured? I believe it has something to do with your build missing something due to incorrect structure.

Comment: @JosephJulian here is the structure of my directory before using the command `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`:

I have all of the files (__init__.py, LISCENCE, mousecontroller.py, README.md, setup.py) in a folder named mousecontroller

Comment: @FreddieRayner, I believe the correct answer has already been posted, but thank you for responding. I concur that your `scripts=` line is missing squared brackets. Additonally, as I suspected, @FlyingTeller has noted something missing from your `.tar.gz`.

Comment: @JosephJulian Thank you! This has solved my problem. It's so annoying how such a small thing caused it to not work, when I had been trying to fix it for hours! Anyways thanks for helping.

Comment: @FreddieRayner Now that your package is updated, I have noticed that you tagged it as OS independent and also built an independent whl. You should make it windows only though as you are using the win32api

Comment: @FlyingTeller thanks for pointing that out for me! I will fix that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `script=` line is not correct, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts):

> The scripts option simply is a **list of files**

You only provided your script as a string, which is split into individual characters when treated as a list. That is why the error message says that `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60u406eb\mousecontroller_e9ecf1693b5a49f6aa898bb92d39281a\m` is not found.

Fix by using squared brackets:

```
scripts=['mousecontroller.py']
```

**Side Note**

```
mousecontroller.py
```

is not in the `.tar.gz` that is available on PyPi. Might be due to the same reason.